# Can we completely avoid Scala and simply use the Play! framework

Tags: java, web-applications, playframework

This is a total newbie question. Is it possible to use the Play! framework without having to use any Scala at all?

Even when I create a pure java app it seems to create the index.scala.html and uses the Scala @ syntax. Are there any samples of a pure Java app on the Play! site?

I dont want to spend time learning the syntax of Scala (however much the documentation reassures me that its "just like java"). So basically i would like the app stack to be HTML,CSS,Jquery and a solid java framework on the server with a db like mongo. Thats it.

If not Play! what (recent) framework could be used?

Comment: Perhaps Spring Roo will help you?

Comment: I recommend you to go Play1.2.x plus Rythm template engine and PlayMorphia module for mongodb access.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Play 2, then yes you can work entirely in java:
You can notice in the documentation, that you can generate response using scala this way

```
public static Result homePage() {
  return ok(views.html.index.render());
}
```

where "index" is some class generated from the internal scala templating engine.
**However**, you can also write your own response, like this:

```
public static Result homePage() {
  return ok("<html><body>Hello world!</body></html>");
}
```

As you can see, you are not pushed here to use scala templating system. What the ok() method want, is the string which is then sent to the client (with HTML OK header). **How you generate the HTML code is entirely on you**. You can use scala template engine, you can generate this string purely by java code or you can write some wrapper and use some totally different library.

So the answer is: yes, you do not have to use scala at all.

See [examples of play 2 controllers without scala](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/JavaActions)

But I strongly advice you to use *at least some* templating system...

Answer (score 2):

Play 2 does indeed create scala for the views, but there is a Groovy module that allows you to write your views in the same way that you did in Play 1.

The link to the Groovy module is here - https://github.com/mbknor/gt-engine-play2

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to Play 1.2.4 (which was released 6 months ago) then you can avoid scala templating and can find example files (inside the folder samples-and-tests) such as "index.html" instead of "index.scala.html"

You can also find older Play documentation if you google "play 1.1 documentation pdf" and there you will find a manual that makes things look much easier. It explains all the examples as well.

Answer (score -1):

I take It you are using Play 2.
You can write your entire app in Java.

However the templating is done using scala. From what I understand this is a small portion of scala which you need to learn and does not require you to dive in fully into the language.

Play 1 uses groovy for templating and has two other templating module (japid and rythm).

Whichever framework you decide to use, it is very unlikely that you will use pure java (think jsp!)

Comment: Rythm syntax is very close to pure Java, say you can do something like `@if (someCondition) {<p>success</p>}` else {<p>fail</p>}, and `@for(User user: users) {<li>@user.name</li>}`